# Showing default error i.e. provide all values In short JSON is not putting values to server

Tags: android, android-studio

```
 class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //creating request handler object
            RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

            //creating request parameters
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("name", name);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("mobile", mobile);
            params.put("password", password);

            //returing the response
            return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(URLs.URL_REGISTER, params);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            try {
                //converting response to json object
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

                int a= obj.getInt("error");
                //if no error in response
                if (a==0) {
                    Snackbar.make(parent_view, obj.getString("alert"), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //starting the OTP activity
                    signintxt.setText("OTP");
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frmframelayout, new fragment_reg_otp(), "reg_otp").addToBackStack("reg_otp").commit();
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(parent_view, obj.getString("alert"), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    //executing the async task
    RegisterUser ru = new RegisterUser();
    ru.execute();
}


  **request handler class**
   public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL, HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {
    URL url;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            String response;

            while ((response = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(response);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

In this I doesn't get any error but It is not accepting / putting values to the server, it shows me the default error which is provide all values . When I told to change the method in the Php code from POST to GET it worked .

I am also sharing my request handler class .
Why this is happening I doesn't know  help to understand this.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. You should create your own Answer with the code you used to solve your problem, then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to accepting your own Answer). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer). However, be sure your question contains enough information so it's possible for anyone to be able to determine your Answer actually is the solution (i.e. not just because you say it is).

Answer (score 1):

Why are you making something complicated? where an easy and clean solution for you???
use volley:
add below dependency to build.gradle:

**implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'**

for POST request:

```
public void RegisterUser(){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            // Example
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // any action....
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

            params.put("exampleKey1", "example value");

            // if integer type value then convert it into string like below
            params.put("key2", Integer.toString(int value));

            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

For GET request:

```
public void RegisterUser(){
String url = "example.com?key=value";
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Example
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // any action....
    }
},
new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
});
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

}

Comment: problem is not solved . Not accepting values to the server.

Comment: may be it's your server settings issue. make sure that "enable_post_data_reading" variable is set to "on" in php.ini. are you using localhost server? if so then try to other localhost server.